# Close div when open a new one (jQuery slide)

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I have multiple divs appearing when clicking on link. Problem is a new div appears below if one is already visible. How can I replace the "old" one with the new one?

```
jQuery("#div_to_show").hide();
jQuery(".toggle_link").show();

jQuery('.toggle_link').click(function(){
jQuery("#div_to_show").slideToggle();


jQuery("#div_to_show2").hide();
jQuery(".toggle_link2").show();

jQuery('.toggle_link2').click(function(){
jQuery("#div_to_show2").slideToggle();


jQuery("#div_to_show3").hide();
jQuery(".toggle_link3").show();

jQuery('.toggle_link3').click(function(){
jQuery("#div_to_show3").slideToggle();
```

DEMO with multiple divs: http://jsfiddle.net/ap2EQ/

Comment: I would also encourage you to go back through all your questions and up vote any answers that were helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple things that can be improved upon in your code.  First you don't need `3` `jQuery document ready` functions.  You just need one to initialize the code when the webpage loads.  You can make use of `classes` to simplify your code.  But mainly what you need to do is hide all the divs before you toggle or make visible the new one.  Hopefully this code will help you see and understand how it works.

HTML

```
<a class="toggle" data-target="iscriversi">...iscriversi</a><br>
<a class="toggle" data-target="collaborare">...collaborare</a><br>
<a class="toggle" data-target="sostenerci">...sostenerci</a>
<div id="iscriversi" class="div">div1</div>
<div id="collaborare" class="div">div2</div>
<div id="sostenerci" class="div">div3</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".div").hide();
  jQuery('.toggle').click(function(){
    jQuery(".div").hide();
    jQuery("#"+$(this).data('target')).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ap2EQ/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the other divs before running slideToggle()

```
jQuery('.iscriversi_toggle').click(function(){
    jQuery("#collaborare").hide();
    jQuery("#sostenerci").hide();
    jQuery("#iscriversi").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a seperate div with no content that you can use to display whatever the user clicked on:

```
<!-- these divs stay hidden; they are just used to store the data you want to display later -->
<div id="iscriversi">div1</div>
<div id="collaborare">div2</div>
<div id="sostenerci">div3</div>

<!-- placeholder where content will be displayed when user clicks -->
<div id="target_container"></div>
```

Then you can use this function to replace the content in the target_container:

```
function replaceDivContent(newDivID) {

   // Get the data from the DIV you want to display.
   newContentFromDiv = jQuery(newDivID).html();

   jQuery('#target_container')
     .hide() // hide so we can use the slide effect later
     .html(newContentFromDiv) // replace content of the placeholder div
     .slideToggle(); // show the placeholder div again using slide effect
}
```

Working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zpYBM/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion to make this all work...

**HTML**

```
<a class="iscriversi_toggle aShow">...iscriversi</a>
<br>
<a class="collaborare_toggle aShow" >...collaborare</a>
<br>
<a class="sostenerci_toggle aShow">...sostenerci</a>

<div id="iscriversi" class="divtoggle">div1</div>
<div id="collaborare"  class="divtoggle">div2</div>
<div id="sostenerci"  class="divtoggle">div3</div>
```

You can see here that I've added a class to each of your `<a>` elements.  The class is `aShow`.   This lets us access all of the anchors at once with the same call.

I've also added a `divtoggle` class to each of your `div` elements.   Same reason.

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Hide all the divtoggle tags, and show the anchors
    jQuery ('.divtoggle').hide();
    jQuery(".aShow").show();

    jQuery('.iscriversi_toggle').click(function(){
    // Hide all the DIVs, and show just the one we want
        jQuery ('.divtoggle').hide();
        jQuery("#iscriversi").slideToggle();
    });

    jQuery('.collaborare_toggle').click(function(){
    // Hide all the DIVs, and show just the one we want        
        jQuery ('.divtoggle').hide();
        jQuery("#collaborare").slideToggle();
    });

    jQuery('.sostenerci_toggle').click(function(){
    // Hide all the DIVs, and show just the one we want        
        jQuery ('.divtoggle').hide();
        jQuery("#sostenerci").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

I've got comments in the code so it's easy to follow.    This is a bit cleaner than what you originally had, and more scalable.   Also, as a side not, you do not need to specify `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` over and over.   You should only use that once.

And finally, here is a jsFiddle demo:   **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ap2EQ/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function(e){
   $("a").each(function(index,element){
   $(element).click(function(){
   var dis = $(element).next().css("display");
   if(dis == 'none')
    {
            $('div').hide(500);

        $(element).next().show(500);

    }else{
    $(element).next().hide(500)
    };

      })
    })

   })
```